# Ceiling Fan: Installed per the manual, but not working. Where's my mistake?

Tags: electrical, wiring, ceiling-fan

**PROJECT:** Replacing an old ceiling fan fan with a new one that has fan+light+remote. The new one is a Hunter "Mill Creek." (Old Hunter fan was basic fan-only model with pull chain, connected to a single switch.)

**STATUS:** New fan is hung, light module attached, and everything wired up per the diagram below (pg 6 in [**installation manual**](https://image.hunterfan.com/3954-01.pdf)).

**PROBLEM:** Neither fan nor light turn on (as activated by remote).

**WHAT I'VE CHECKED:**

1. Remote batteries working? (Yes, they are brand new, and the indicator light on the remote turns on when pressing remote buttons.)
2. Remote paired to receiver? (Yes, manual says it should already come paired, but I also tried the backup pairing instructions in the manual.)
3. Circuit breaker on? (Yes)
4. Wall switch turned on? (Yes)
5. Wall switch sending power to the ceiling box? (Yes, confirmed with tester immediately before installation. Also, the old fan worked fine.)
6. All wire nut connections tight? (Yes, installed carefully, and pulled firmly on every single wire to confirm good connection.)
7. 9-pin connector between fan motor and light module connected right? (Yes, all colors line up and connectors are firmly seated.)
8. Light bulbs screwed in all the way? (Yes, checked.)
9. Light bulbs themselves working? (Yes, checked in another fixture.)
10. Fan motor mechanically blocked? (No, blades are able to move freely.)
11. Receiver internally defective? (Unlikely. I had bought two of these new fans, so tried swapping the receivers out, and still no luck.)
12. Fan motor internally defective? (Unlikely, for the same reason. Tried the second motor I have here and no difference.)

Novice electrician here, so all out of ideas. **Anything else I can try?**

[image: Hunter "Mill Creek" wiring diagram]

Comment: If instructions were followed, the only possibility of a mistake should be mixing up the two blacks from the fan.  Recheck all connections just in case.  Just because they are tight, does not necessary mean electrical connection is good.  A bit of odd wording of white grounded and black ungrounded, it is true, but odd.

Comment: I’ve had situations (not Hunter, but other decent brand) where the pairing instructions were wrong in print. Called tech support to get up and running.

Comment: The instructions PRESUME that your switch/power source is wired up a particular way to match.  My guess: It's not.  There is no standard for how to wire light/fan switches.   Also, why did you get a new fan? Was something wrong with the old one?

Comment: @crip659 - Thanks. Have tried and retried the connections several times, still no luck unfortunately.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate - Thanks for the suggestion. Have got a message into manufacturer as well.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica - Ceiling box outlet is fed by one multi-wire cable that has one each: black, white, red, & bare. Black/white pair tests at 120v. Red is capped by itself (and not connected to anything at wall switch). Am hoping to upgrade look of old fan and add some needed light as well. Thanks.

Comment: @Scott OK, I wanted to exclude the possibility of a wiring fault having killed the original fan. You have tested hot/neutral good.  Any chance. you can wire up a receptacle to the black/white and make sure a light comes on if plugged into the receptacle? That would exclude phantom voltage.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica - Wired up a receptacle (and added grounding wire as well). A plugged in lamp works as normal, and plug-in tester read as correctly installed. Is that what you were asking?

Comment: Testing an outlet/lamp would confirm that the wiring through the switch and to the ceiling box is correct. Frankly, that leaves you with a defective fan. However, you indicated that you tried _both_ fans and _neither_ works. Getting two defective fans right out of the box is _very_ unlikely, but not impossible. I'd confirm the remote pairing from the manufacturer, but it seems that you've done it right. Maybe give us a picture of your actual wiring, in addition to the diagram - maybe someone can spot an error somewhere.

Comment: @Scott yes, you just positively validated power to that location (specifically: neutral and eliminated any chance of phantom voltage).  Say, do these fans have remotes?  Are the remotes matched to the fan? Any chance you mixed them up?

Comment: So it sounds like you bought two identical fans. Is one of them up and running somewhere? Or did you get the second one when the first one failed? Since neither light or fan work and there is power, the problem is likely to be the receiver or remote. If you can't get either to work, then there is a chance you got two bad fans. You might try wiring one of the fans (without blades) somewhere safe and seeing if you can get the lights to work or the motor to spin.  Getting one to work anywhere else would tell you if it is a fan issue or an installation issue.